# Openid Connect State param without cookies

Tags: openid-connect

The spec recommends the use of the `state` param to help mitigate CSRF-lie attack vectors. However, if the auth workflow is being implemented with token based auth rather than session based auth for the consumer's users what would be the recommendation to manage the state considering it could not be set on a session.

Answer (score 2):

I realize your question specifically asks *without cookies*, but since you state your goal is to avoid backend sessions, you could issue the browser a short-lived, signed cookie containing the state. By signing it, you know you issued it, and it hasn't been tampered with. Make it HttpOnly and Secure for good measure.

I'm currently trying something like the following with Express.js:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
...
app.use(cookieParser('your-secret'));
```

In the backend code that generates the redirect to the authorization server, I store the state in a signed cookie and include it in the redirect url to the authorization server:

```
    const state = uuidv4();
    res.cookie(
        'state',
        state,
        {
            maxAge: 60 * 1000,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            signed: true // important
        }
    );
```

Then in your callback handler, verify the cookie state (`req.signedCookies.state`) matches the query string param state (`req.query.state`), then optionally delete the cookie or just let it expire on its own.

Even though the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) says this approach ("cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie") is "typical", I had a hard time finding anyone doing it this way. I did find [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/wiki/Cookies) which sounds like it's doing this, but I didn't dig into its source:

> a short-lived "state" cookie that correlates the authentication request and response

It's been a year since you asked, if you found another way around this I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF concerns browser-based user agents. The `state` should cryptographically be bound to the user agent. Since the only mechanism to store the binding over a request/response pair available to a browser-based user agent is a cookie or HTML storage, you're confined to those options.